# Parallel inner loop, sequential outer: can I make mcfork faster or keep sessions somehow?

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, domc

When writing a nested loop where the outer loop needs to be sequential and the inner loop depends on the previous iteration via a very simple object, is there a way to reduce the overhead from communicating between sessions multiple times?

Here's an example using `doMC` and `foreach`:

```r
library(doMC)
library(tictoc)

registerDoMC(3)

tic()
a <- runif(100)
for(i in seq_len(333)){
  a <- foreach(j = 1:100, .combine = c) %dopar% {
    sqrt(a[j])*sqrt(max(a))
  } 
}
toc()
#> 7.669 sec elapsed

tic()
a <- runif(100)
for(i in seq_len(333)){
  a <- foreach(j = 1:100, .combine = c) %do% {
    sqrt(a[j])*sqrt(max(a))
  } 
}
toc()
#> 5.224 sec elapsed
```

<sup>Created on 2019-07-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Because the calculations in the inner loop are very simple the overhead introduced from creating multiple sessions and transfering the data make the parallel version slower than the sequential one.

After profiling the code, as expected, the time difference comes mostly from `mcfork`, but since the calculation is so simple and differs between calls only due to the `a` vector, I was wondering if there is a way to make the sessions persist between `foreach` calls and send only the `a` vector between each call (I think this should be a lot faster than forking the entire session).

Is there a way of achieving that with the session forking structure of `doMC`? Is there another parallel backend capable of this kind solution (making sessions persist with small changes between tasks)?

Comment: Could you `set.seed(1)`? And show the result of your example?

Comment: Usually not a good idea to parallelize the inner loop.
You can maybe try to rewrite your problem. E.g. here, you could return everything and compute max only at the end. I don't totally understand what your question is.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure parallel computing can be recursive. So if result `n+1` relies on result `n`, there's no way to be parallel without restructuring your algorithm.

For your specific problem, it wasn't truly recursive when `max(a) > 0`. Where `a[j] == max(a)`, your inner loop would evaluate to `max(a)`. That is:

`sqrt(a[which.max(a)]) * sqrt(max(a)) == max(a)`

So for each loop, `sqrt(max(a))` will always be the same when `max(a) > 0`. Furthermore, we can work on simplifying the other portion of the loop:

```
#i = 1
sqrt(a[1]) * sqrt(max(a))
#i = 2
sqrt(sqrt(a[1]) * sqrt(max(a))) * sqrt(max(a))
#simplifies to
a[1]^(1/4) * max(a) ^ (3/4)
```

This loop can be translated into:

```
a^(1 / 2^n) * max(a)^((2^n - 1) / (2^n))
```

I know this doesn't directly answer your question but it supports @F. Privé's comment: try to rethink the problem to see if it can be vectorized. For example, even your example loop could be vectorized:

```
for(i in seq_len(n)){
  a <- sqrt(a) * sqrt(max(a)) 
  }
```

For `seq_len(5)`, here is the performance of the methods:

```
Unit: microseconds
             expr      min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
  do_par_original 125089.5 128144.6 128089.30 128462.3 129352.3 129397.8     5
  inner_as_vector   3095.4   3183.0   9754.70   3288.2   3307.9  35899.0     5
 fully_vectorized     17.7     24.8     25.76     28.1     28.1     30.1     5
```